# Assign value to $_POST = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Tags: php

I'd like to assign `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to my post variable `$_POST['fes-name']`.

This is what I've attempted, but it's not working.
When I echo `$_POST['fes-name']`, I'd like to get the browsers details.

```
$user_agent = $_POST;
$user_agent['fes-name'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `echo $_POST['fes-name'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` ?! Why do you want to assign a value to a `$_POST` variable?!

Comment: Manipulating `$_POST` tends to imply that you're doing something a little funky with your code. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PHP assigns an array to a variable it does so by copying. So, for example:

```
$a = array(3); 
$b = $a; 
$b[0]=1; 
print_r($a);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
*/
print_r($b);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
*/
```

You have two options if you want to change `$_POST`. Either you can assign to `$_POST` directly:

```
$_POST['fes-name'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Or, [you could assign `$user_agent` by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), and then changing it will change `$_POST` as well.

```
$user_agent =& $_POST;
$user_agent['fes-name'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```